# 32bit ODBC and 64bit SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, odbc, 32bit-64bit

I have a 64bit server running Windows Server 2008 and MSSQL 2008, both in 64bit.
I also have an application which queries a second system but can only work in windows server 2003 32bit.
I want to connect both systems via a service that would run on the 32bit system and connecting to MSSQL via ODBC.

What are the pitfalls? Has anyone tried something similar?

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter if the server is running in 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Network communication is not changed because the server has a diff CPU.  As far as yhour client is concerned, it doesnt even know what the server is running on.

Comment: This is obvious :-)
The question is are there any potential clashes in the data when connecting through a 32bit ODBC driver to a 64Bit server?

Comment: @bugmeister: The datatypes are fixed, an int is an int, a bit is a bit, a varchar is a varchar, the precisions(number of bytes used) are set when you establish your column definitions. They are unaffected by the bit width of the CPU

Comment: @bugmeister: I thought it was obvious too but you still asked :)  There is no difference, clashes, etc that are possible... It's seamless regardless of the 32/64Bit combinations.